# Gateway API works only with deployed Ingress

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-compute-engine, kubernetes-ingress, api-gateway, gateway

Following setup: I have a web application running on the GKE cluster, and I wanted it to be accessible through the VPC Network and Company VPN. So, first, I decided to use an internal application load balancer with an ingress controller. It looked like this, and it was working fine:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: *****-ingress
  namespace: ******
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce-internal"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.regional-static-ip-name: "rilb-vip-europe-west1-01"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - ******
    secretName: s0015-prd-ssl-certificate
  rules:
  - host: "paketmap.s0015.prd.gcp.hc.de"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: ***-service
            port:
              number: 80

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ****-service
  namespace: ****
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: ****
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80           
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
```

Later, I realized that I wanted some features like redirect or shared namespaces from the Gateway API. So, I built a setup with Gateway API for my application. Here, I will show just a regular test setup because problems begin already there:

I created two new namespaces with a matching label:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: infra-ns
  labels:
    # Value of the matchLabel does not matter 
    shared-gateway-access: "not-important"
```

service and deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: site-v1
  namespace: infra-ns
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: site
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: site
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: whereami
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/whereami:v1.1.3
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: METADATA
          value: "site-v1"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: site-v1
  namespace: infra-ns
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
spec:
  selector:
    app: site
    version: v1
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
```

Gateway API:

```
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: internal-http
  namespace: my-test
spec:
  gatewayClassName: gke-l7-rilb
  listeners:
  - name: http
    protocol: HTTP
    port: 80
    allowedRoutes:
      namespaces:
        from: Selector
        selector:
          matchLabels:
            shared-gateway-access: "not-important"
```

httproute:

```
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: HTTPRoute
metadata:
  name: site
  namespace: infra-ns
spec:
  parentRefs:
  - kind: Gateway
    name: internal-http
    namespace: my-test
  rules:
  - backendRefs:
    - name: site-v1
      port: 80
```

GKE version: 1.27.5-gke.200
We using shared VPC

The problem I have is that somehow my Gateway API works only if I have one ingress deployed. It doesn't matter if this ingress is attached to a service or not. If I don't have this ingress deployed, then I have an unhealthy NEG, and if I try to open this test application, I receive the message: "no healthy upstream."

For example, if I have a running ingress that is completely in another namespace and a Gateway test deployment like I shared, I can reach the IP address from the Gateway API, so it works all fine. If I now remove this ingress controller, I will get an unhealthy NEG in my Gateway API test and the message "no healthy upstream."

This is weird because I tried a 1:1 setup in my private GKE environment, and it works fine. What could cause such a relationship between Ingress and Gateway API? Maybe somehow the Only-proxy-subnet is attached only to Ingress? I don't know.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about specific programming issues.

Comment: Why you have then tags like ingress or api gateway?